# Where is the postgresql wal located? How can I specify a different path?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a database with the data files and the wal on different filesystems. I want the wal on a separate server over NFS, to avoid a loss of data in case of a fs/disk crash.

Where is the wal written?

Can I force it to a different location than the default via the configuration?

I'm on 9.1 if that matters.

Thanks.

Comment: And what will you do if a separate server with WAL will have "fs/disk crash"? The whole idea of "WAL on separate machine" doesn't sound good.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: the Postgres Wiki says: "*you might consider relocating the WAL (pg_xlog directory) to a separate disk to ease I/O load on the rest of the database*" (see the link in my answer)

Comment: In my opinion, putting your WAL on an NFS mount is a bad idea. You want the best performance and reliability for you WAL and I don't think an NFS mount can offer this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name On a separate disk but not on a separate machine. The reason of a separate disk is to split i/o for better performance. Moving WAL to separate machine wont give you performance benefits (and most likely will do the opposite). And with two machines involved your DB will crash if any machine crash -> less reliability.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: you are right. I somehow overlooked the "separate server" part.

Comment: In case of loosing the main data, the WAL directory alone would be useless. What you want is probably archiving the WAL files to a separate disk coupled with hot backup. See the `archive_mode` parameter.

Comment: @Igor Romanchenko: If the remote server disapear, then my DB will stop functioning, but this way there is no window where I can lose data (unless both server crash at the same time, but they are in different data centers, in different cities).

Comment: @YvesDorfsman If your server with WAL will get its FS corrupted you will lose ALL data. You wont be able to restore your database is you lose any part of WAL log.

Comment: @YvesDorfsman if you need reliability - just set up postgres replica on remote server. This way you will not lose any data in case of server fault.

Comment: @Will: My writing to the server is severly limited by external factors. Writing performance will never be an issue.

Comment: @DanielVérité: I understand, and I am configuring wal_level to hot_standby, and running PostreSQL on the NFS server with standby_mode on.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: I also need to copy files between the two servers, hence the original requirement for NFS. The two issues I have with streaming replication are:

1) there is still a small window for losing data

2) it isn't encrypted, so I would have to setup an ssh tunnel etc... Since I already have encrypted NFS, I thought I'd use that.

Comment: @YvesDorfsman 1) with synchronous replication there is no window for losing data (and it probably will be faster then "WAL on NFS") 2) Database connection can use SSL encription if it is set up properly (same encryption method that is used in ssh). 3) With "WAL on NFS" there can be a window for losing data if NFS does not `fsync` correctly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The WAL files are written to the directory `pg_xlog` inside of the data directory. Starting with Postgres 10, this directory was renamed to `pg_wal`

E.g. `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal`

See the manual for details:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-configuration.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-configuration.html

If I'm not mistaken, this directory name can not be changed. But it can be a symbolic link that points to a different disk.

As a matter of fact this is actually recommended to tune WAL performance (See here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Installation_and_Administration_Best_practices#WAL_Directory)

Comment: Do google around postgresql+nfs though. If your NFS setup isn't 100% solid you'll be storing up trouble for yourself

Comment: Hoping @Yves and readers won't miss the irony in that whereas the answer is based on a performance recommandation (channel the xlog to a different disk for more bandwidth), the question is about putting xlog on remote storage, which is likely to be a unbearable performance-killer.

Comment: @DanielVérité I do understand the performance penalty. I am looking at IgorRomancheko comment about streaming over SSL, and after some googling, this might actually be easier, and as a lot of you guys have commentd, less troublesome, than doing wal on NFS.

Comment: starting with postgres 10 the directory is called pg_wal instead of pg_xlog

Answer (score 6):

To Copy the WAL Directory to another file path/disk drive, follow these steps below:

### Descriptive Steps

1. Turn off Postgres to protect against corruption
2. Copy WAL directory (by default on Ubuntu - `/var/lib/postgresql/<version>/main/pg_wal`) to new file path using `rsync`. It will preserve file/folder permissions and folder structure with the `-a` flag. You should leave off the training slash.
3. Verify the contents copied correctly
4. Rename `pg_wal` to `pg_wal-backup` in the Postgres data directory (`$PG_DATA`)
5. Create a symbolic link to the new path to `pg_wal` in the Postgres data directory (`$PG_DATA`) and update the permissions of the symbolic link to be the `postgres` user
6. Start Postgres and verify that you can connect to the database
7. Optionally, delete the `pg_wal-backup` directory in the Postgres data directory (`$PG_DATA`)

### Matching Commands

```
sudo service postgresql stop

sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal /<new_path>
ls -la /<new_path>

sudo mv /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal-backup
sudo ln -s /<new_path> /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal
sudo chown -h postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal

sudo service postgresql start && sudo service postgresql status
# Verify DB connection using your db credentials/information
psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432

rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_wal-backup
```